# Can you change form question IDs in Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created many forms for work and initially, I built one and just copied the form for all the different things I needed. Now They have Expanded over time and have more funtionallity. One problem I ran into is I copy my script to each one and do a lot of "fill form" functions, that based on answers from previous forms will give you the possible answers to the newest form. But now that I'm not copying the form and just building out all my questions have different ID's compared to the other forms and it adds hours of work to get around these changes. Is there any way to change question ID's on a form so that I can make them the same across forms?

Thank you, even if it's a big NO.

Comment: I don't see any set id methods.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*It is not possible*

### Workaround

You can get all the questions using [Form.getItems()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getitems) and checking that the type of each item corresponds to a question. Check [Enum ItemType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-type). Finally, you can obtain the `id` of each item with [Item.getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#getid).

### Code

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var items = form.getItems()
  var questionTypes = ['CHECKBOX', 'CHECKBOX_GRID', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DURATION', 'GRID', 'LIST', 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE', 'PARAGRAPH_TEXT', 'SCALE', 'TEXT', 'TIME']
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var type = items[i].getType().name()
    if (questionTypes.includes(type)) {
      console.log(items[i].getTitle())
      console.log(items[i].getId())
    }
  }
}
```